# 抽象クラスを継承したクラスをインナークラスとしてprivateで宣言し、外部からアクセスしたい

Tags: java, junit

```
■MyAbstractClass.java
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public MyAbstractClass() {
    }
    public abstract int notifyAbs(int a);
}

■MyClassAbstractInnnerClass.java
public class MyClassAbstractInnnerClass{
    private MyAbstractClass testAbstract = new MyAbstractClass() {
        @Override
        public int notifyAbs(int a) {
            return a;
        }
    };
}
```

上記のような抽象クラスを継承したprivateクラスのインスタンス(testAbstract)が持つメソッド(notifyAbs)への外部からのアクセスは可能でしょうか？
JUnitでnotifyAbsの試験をしたいのですが、アクセス方法がわからずに困っています。

Answer (score 1):

「junit privateメソッド テスト」でネットを検索すればいろいろ出てきます。
たとえば以下。

```
Method method = Sample.class.getDeclaredMethod("getName", Integer.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
String resutl = (String)method.invoke(new Sample(), new Integer(1));
```

参考：　http://javatechnology.net/java/private-junit/

Answer (score 1):

ご回答ありがとうございます。privateクラスやprivateメソッド、インナークラスへのアクセスについては実現できて‌​いるのですが、掲題のようなabstrac‌​tクラスを継承したフィールドでかつ、中に‌​メソッドがあるケースではどうしても実現が‌​できませんでした。

```
public class MyClassAbstractInnnerClass{
    private InnerClass testAbstract = new InnerClass();
    public class InnerClass extends MyAbstractClass{
        @Override
        public int notifyAbs(int a) {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

よって、上記のようにフィールドの宣言と処理をわけることでnotifyAbs()へのアクセスを実現しました。